# python - Run Az CLI commands to get Azure AD group details of a user

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-cli

Getting error - `Insufficient privileges to complete the operation` when I try to run the Az CLI code from python using Azure function with system assigned managed identity enabled.
I want to run the below Azure-Cli code from python to get the Azure AD group details of a user with id.

```
az ad user get-member-groups --id "someid@somedomain.com"
```

Here is my code to run the same.

```
DefaultAzureCredential(exclude_interactive_browser_credential=False)    
    args_str1 = 'login --identity --allow-no-subscriptions'
    args_str2 = 'ad user get-member-groups --id someid@domain.com'
    args1 = args_str1.split()
    args2 = args_str2.split()
    cli = get_default_cli()
    cli.invoke(args1)
    cli.invoke(args2)
    if cli.result.result:
       logging.info(cli.result.result)
    elif cli.result.error:
       logging.info(cli.result.error)
```

Authentication is completing when i check the log.

```
ManagedIdentityCredential will use App Service managed identity
```

Comment: Is that `ad user get ...` command working on azure bash cloud shell? And what is the rbac role you're having in Azure AD?

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT:- The cli command is working fine on command prompt with my account and the results are getting. My Rbac role is Contributor towards the subscription. But from this Azure Function we should use Managed Identity. I have set the access for the managed identity to contributor of the same subscription.

Answer (score 1):

> Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

I believe you're missing the required API permissions after assigning the Managed Identity.

> Az CLI code from python using Azure function with system assigned managed identity enabled.

Go to the Azure Portal > Azure AD > Select your Application added in the App Registrations > API Permissions > **Delegated Permissions** > Give the below permissions

[image]

[image]

If this doesn't help to resolve the error `Insufficient privileges to complete the operation`, then try assigning same permissions on the **Application Permissions** level:

[image]